# Recursively called tkinter widget only shows twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been working a program for Authors of STO (Star Trek Online) foundry missions. Basically I am making program to show a dialog tree.

Half-way through getting through my functionality work (I worry about aesthetics later) I discovered I could only call the widgets when adding a reply dialog. If I want to create a reply to a reply (Third Level) It simply will not show, but I get no error.

### [Screenshot of max vertical](http://postimg.org/image/vuoori1rj/)

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
class Dialog(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.widgets()
        self.grid()
        self.button_num=0
    def widgets(self):
        self.charname=tk.Label(self,text="Contact")
        self.charname.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.char=ttk.Entry(self)
        self.char.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.animname=tk.Label(self,text="Animation")
        self.animname.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.anim=ttk.Entry(self)
        self.anim.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.msgname=tk.Label(self,text="Dialog")
        self.msgname.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.msg=tk.Text(self,font="Arial 8",width=20,height=5)
        self.msg.grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.add=ttk.Button(self,text="Add Button",command=self.add_output).grid(row=3,column=0)
        self.resp=ttk.Entry()
        self.arr=ttk.Label(text=""" |
 |
\/""")
    def add_output(self):
        self.resp.grid(column=self.button_num,row=4)
        self.arr.grid(column=self.button_num,row=5)
        dialog=Dialog()
        dialog.grid(column=self.button_num,row=6)
        self.button_num+=1

class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.widgets()
        self.grid()
    def widgets(self):
        Dialog()
Application(master=tk.Tk()).mainloop().title("FoundryPADD 0.1.0")
```

Comment: What does "could only call the dialog twice vertically" mean? What's stopping you from calling it a third time? Also, what do you mean by "calling it vertically"? How do you call a function "vertically"? The words "horizontal" and "vertical" appear nowhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry, badly worded. I will edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `add_output` function always puts things in the same row, so they simply appear on top of previous items on the same row. You need to keep track of how many rows you have, and increment the row appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of that. Serves me right for pulling an all nighter on it!